# Leaflet marker instead of circles for search result

Tags: r, leaflet, interactive

Leaflet allows to implement an interactive search feature into the map like this

```
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)

leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addSearchOSM()
```

However, the results are always showed with a circle marker. How do I change it to the classical pin marker? I'd expect it to be part of the `searchOptions()` function, but I can't find an according paramater.